# How to redirect the user by using Ajax call on specific Controller and action

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Below is my Javascript function which will do update on the click of Update button.

```
function UpdateData() {

    var obj = {
        "testData": $("#hdn_EditdsVal").val(),
        "feature": $("#hdn_EditdsVal").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@(Url.Action("UpdatePlanFeatVal", "SuperAdmin"))',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),            
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {
            // want to redirect the user using ControllerName/ActionMethod
        },
        error: function (err) {

        }
    });
}
```

And my controller

```
public ActionResult UpdatePlanFeatVal(string testData,string feature)
    {
            var cmd = (object)null;
            testData = testData.Trim();
            string[] words = testData.Split(':');

            XDocument _xdoc = new XDocument(new XElement("Pricing"));

            foreach (string word in words)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                {
                    string[] wor = word.Split('_');

                    _xdoc.Root.Add(
                            new XElement("row",
                            new XElement("FeatureId", wor[1]),
                            new XElement("PlanId", wor[2]),
                            new XElement("Unit", wor[3])
                ));
                }

            }
            using (StoredProcedureContext sc = new StoredProcedureContext())
            {                    
                cmd = sc.EditPricing(_xdoc);             
            }

        return View("ManageSubscriptionPlan");
   }
```

It is not redirecting me to that view and also did some google and found that i have to this thing in Javascript itself and call the url using `OnSuccess` option. Any idea how to do postback by using javascript in my scenario.

And also don't go through the code as it is modified before posting. I just want redirect to be happen after update.

Comment: The whole purpose of ajax is to stay on the same page, and using ajax to post data when you want to redirect is just pointless. Do a normal submit and save yourself some code and improve performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your javascript function use on success of Ajax.

```
function UpdateData() {

var testData= $("#hdn_EditdsVal").val();
var feature= $("#hdn_EditdsVal").val();
};
$.ajax({
    url: '@(Url.Action("UpdatePlanFeatVal", "SuperAdmin"))',
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { testData: testData, feature: feature },       
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")';
    },
    error: function (err) {

    }
});
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.i got my answer but still marking this as answer because of no other option :P